# How to prevent HTML-autocompletion for specified tag in Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

For example input-tag:

```
String html = "<html><head></head><body><input name='user'></input></body></html>";
Elements input = Jsoup.parse(html).select("input");

for (Element element : input)
   System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(element.outerHtml());
```

Result:

```
<html><head></head><body><input name='user'/></body></html>
```

1) But it is necessary so:

```
<html><head></head><body><input name='user'></input></body></html>
```

2) And as by means of Jsoup to distinguish `"<input.../>"` from `"<input...> </input...>"`

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
 Elements input = Jsoup.parse(html).select("input");
 for(Element element:elements){
      System.out.println(element.tag().isSelfClosing());
 }
```

[documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Tag.html#isSelfClosing%28%29)

Comment: Thanks, it's true for (2), but it is necessary that (1) also worked.

Comment: the select("input") should select both. then you can say if isSelfClosing doSlefClosing() else doSomethingElse() ?